# Connect to ODBC Database with Java (not Access)

Tags: java, odbc, pervasive

I have an ODBC database on Windows Server 2008. Typically I use Access or PHP when I want to work with it, but for reasons I need to connect to it with Java now and it's proving more difficult than I thought it would. Most other questions on this topic are dealing with MS Access, but I'm not in this case and while maybe I could create an MDB file with linked tables then use something like [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) I really don't want to try going there.

So in PHP I can connect to the database with the line:

$conn = odbc_connect("ODBC;ServerName=127.0.0.0;DSN={$odbc_name};",$user,$password);

Is there something equivalent I can do with jdk1.8.0_181? Or is this something where I'd have to revert back to jdk1.7 and use ODBC Bridge?

Edit: I should add that the DB I'm trying to access is not on SQL Server, but rather a more obscure platform called Pervasive SQL. It is still ODBC though.

Comment: [JDBC info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Microsoft provides a good straight forward demo on how to connect to an SQL server database there, but another problem is I'm not using SQL server. The database I need is on a more obscure platform called PervasiveSQL. I can access it in PHP with the given code, or in Access I choose a table from the ODBC data source and have the DB's listed under the Machine Data Source list.

Comment: What version of Pervasive?   There is both a JDBC driver and an ODBC driver for recent versions of PSQL.  JDBC documentation: http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/#page/jdbc%2Fjdbctasks.htm%23

Comment: It's PSQL 10. I see the PSQL connection example in there so I'll give it a try and see if it works with this version.

Comment: Yeah this should be what I need and my pervasive install has the correct jar/dl files to add to the class path/path, but so far haven't been able to get the "pervasive" library to load in Java: Class.forName("com.pervasive.jdbc.v2.Driver").